# Ошибка при команде npx/yarn create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, yarn

Пробовал с --template typescript и без него.[image: Текст ошибки]

Comment: Логи вставлять лучше как текст, а не картинку

Comment: А у вас точно есть свободное место на диске? =)

Comment: Точно! Спасибо)